# In a html css angular table that is scrollable through overflow-x, is there a way to fix the right-most column?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a html css angular table that is scrollable through overflow-x, is there a way to fix the right-most column so that when i scroll from left to right, that column stays there?

I tried the sticky property, as well as creating two tables right next to eachother (which does not accomplish the task successfully. I am thinking that i should overlay two tables on top of eachother but i am not sure how i should go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: sticky` appears to work fine on chrome and firefox:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

table {
  width: 1000px;
}

.sticky-col {
  width: 40px;
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
  <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th class="sticky-col">3</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1,1</td><td>1,2</td><td class="sticky-col">1,3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2,1</td><td>2,2</td><td class="sticky-col">2,3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3,1</td><td>3,2</td><td class="sticky-col">3,3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```